# Deploying Maven based JSF project to Tomcat results in java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, classnotfoundexception

I've been trying to deploy JSF components on Apache Tomcat 8. Everytime I restart and deploy server I get ClassNotFoundException.

**LOG**

```
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1451 ms
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 191 ms
Connected to server
[2014-07-20 10:31:35,659] Artifact Java:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Faces Servlet as unavailable
Jul 20, 2014 10:31:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1588)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>\index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And here is maven dependency

**pom.xml**

```
 <!-- JSF dependency -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

*This dependency I added later when I was trying to deploy with GlassFish*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also tried with GlassFish 4.0 but unable to resolve the problem.

**EDIT**

I updated POM with these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I'm still not able to deploy with Tomcat 8.0.9. When I deploy using console manager of tomcat I get XML parsing error on every page.

Comment: For anyone else struggling with this see the [instructions](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra) for adding the Mojarra dependencies to Tomcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For tomcat you have to have both jsf-api and jsf-impl since tomcat don't have bundled JSF. Please add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Update the version to which ever version you need.

Comment: I updated as you said and also updated POM and question. Please reply.

Comment: You added in provided scope. Remove the scope tag and try.

Comment: This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: But I can now deploy with glassfish 4, problem still persists with tomcat. Tomcat giving 404.

Comment: As said tomcat dont have JSF bundled, either you have to bundle the JSF jars in your WEB-INF/lib or you have to copy the JSF jar in <tomcat_home>/lib. Check https://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2009/12/29/jsf-20-and-tomcat

Comment: I'm very much confused here. I added JSF dependency in the maven's POM, then why I need to add JAR explicitly?

Comment: Is jsf-api and jsf-impl in provided scope? If so it wont be in your WEB-INF/lib since tomcat dont have JSF jars you are getting ClassNotFoundException. Also you are deploying in standalone tomcat or maven tomcat plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58794/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-karthikeyan-vaithilingam).